# Changing useragent if ipad

Tags: javascript, user-agent

What I want to do is detect if the user is using an iPad, then change the useragent to iPhone. But I also want to ensure the page detects this change before page load..

I've tried doing this but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var navigator = new Object; 
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
if (userAgent.Contains("ipad;"))
{
    navigator.userAgent = 'iPhone';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The userAgent is readonly you can not set it to anything.

You are using `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();` which is not valid javascript. This is `c#` which your browser can not execute.

Instead look at the `navigator.userAgent`

```
var nav = '';
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) {
  nav = 'Its an iPad';
} else {
  nav = 'Its some other device';
}

console.log(nav);
```